# Confused about multiple different containers using a single data volume containers

Tags: docker, containers

I've been investigating docker recently, and I moving on to start to look at data volume containers, and how I can persist information between sessions, and I'm alittle confused.

Can a single data volume container be used in the majority of cases?

Lets take a simple one, the library/postgres image, in its dockerfile it exposes a volume /var/lib/postgresql/data  Suppose I mapped that locally to /docker/db_data in a single container setup, I understand that the contents of /var/lib/postgresql/data would be found in my laptops /docker/db_data folder.

But what happens if you want to branch out and have another container running Jenkins, for example, which exposes /var/jenkins_home as a volume.  Initially I would have mapped that to another folder on my laptop, like for example /docker/jenkins_data.

But if I want to enable a data volume container to manage both of these, how can this be done?

Lets say we want to map both containers to directories on my laptop, /docker/db_data and /docker/jenkins_data

Or am I doing this wrong, would it be considered best practises if I used 2 data volume containers, and kept it simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Lets take a simple one, the library/postgres image, in its dockerfile it exposes a volume /var/lib/postgresql/data Suppose I mapped that locally to /docker/db_data in a single container setup, I understand that the contents of /var/lib/postgresql/data would be found in my laptops /docker/db_data folder.

Not exactly. You can mount a directory from your laptop into a container with `-v /docker/db_data:/var/lib/postgressql/data`. If `/var/lib/postgressql/data` already exists in the container, it will be overwritten with the content of `/docker/db_data`.

However, if you use `-v /var/lib/postgressql/data` (*not* mounting a host directory), any files that the image has in `/var/lib/postgressql/data` will be copied into the volume.

You can see the actual location of the data for a volume with the `docker inspect` command, eg `docker inspect postgressql` will show you something like…

`"Volumes": {
    "/var/lib/postgressql/data": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/[some_guid_like_string]"
}`

> But if I want to enable a data volume container to manage both of these, how can this be done?

A container can have multiple volumes with multiple `-v` arguments. In your case if you wanted one data volume container with 2 volumes, you would first create a container to serve as the data volume container with:

`docker create -v /var/lib/postgressql/data -v /var/jenkins_home --name mydata ubuntu /bin/true`

Note the 2 volumes. You `docker create` because the data container does not need to be running to store data.

Now your postgres and jenkins containers can access the volumes using the `--volumes-from` flag. Here's an example for postgres:

`docker run --volumes-from mydata --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres`

With `--volumes-from`, the postgres container will use both the volumes from the `mydata` container, although the postgres one only really cares about `/var/lib/postgressql/data`.

> would it be considered best practises if I used 2 data volume containers, and kept it simple?

I'm not sure about best practice, but I'd say there's no reason for 1 data volume container to manage the data of two unrelated containers. I'd go with separate data volume containers for each.

If, later on, you needed to do something like backup or migrate the data for both postgres and jenkins, you could create another container on the fly with multiple `--volumes-from` and [back up](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) the whole thing. It's pretty flexible.